# How do I retrieve the next higher number in a list?

Tags: c#, list, linq

I want to extract the next highest number after `myNumber` from the list `list`. The list is always sorted.

```cs
List<int> list = new List<int>();

int myNumber = 26

list.Add(2);     
list.Add(3);     
list.Add(7);
list.Add(9);     
list.Add(13);     
list.Add(22);
list.Add(26);     
list.Add(29);     
list.Add(45);
```

As you can see the next higher number to 26 is 29 so it should return it. 
I want to capture than number in a separate int result.

```cs
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: What about if your number does not included in the list ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the last index of element in a list, then get the next element or return `0` (or any other default value), if end of list is reached

```cs
var index = list.LastIndexOf(myNumber);
var result = index < list.Count - 1 ? list[index + 1] : 0;
```

You can also throw an exception in case when last element is reached

```cs
var result = index < list.Count - 1 ? list[index + 1] : throw new Exception("End of list");
```

According to comments, if number is out of the list (`index` equals `-1`), and the closest number is needed, additional check might be used

```cs
var index = list.LastIndexOf(myNumber);
var highest = index >= 0 && index < list.Count - 1 ? list[index + 1] : list[list.Count - 1];
var lowest = index > 0 ? list[index - 1] : list[0];
```

Comment: @lakersfan in this case you might use element at `index - 1` instead of `index + 1` (and check that `index > 0`)

Comment: When myNumber = 47, I get 2, and for the next lowestnumber it's undefined. How do I make it so that if it is a number out of the list, it catches the next closest ie result for next hightest is 45 and result for next lowest is also 45

Comment: @lakersfan if number is out of the list, the `index` will be equal `-1`. You can check `if (index ==  -1)` and get the first (the lowest) or the last (the highest number) from the list

Comment: @lakersfan I've added to the answer the code snippets to reflect the situation, when number is of the list, according to your questions

Answer (score 2):

As the list is sorted you can use [List.BinarySearch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.binarysearch?view=netcore-3.1) to find the item in O(log N) rather than O(N):

```
var index = list.BinarySearch(myNumber);
if(index >= 0)
{
  int nextNumber = list[index + 1];
}
else
{
  // Not found
}
```

Comment: Your `index < 0` is already the "Not Found" case (and `~index` is already the index of the first bigger neighbour). The `+1` should be in the `else` (found) case. Also keep in mind that if the list can contain duplicates it might be better to search for `myNumber + 1`. And the whole thing will crash if the searched number is the biggest number in the list. Apart from that I love the BinarySearch solution

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your list is not always sorted.

```cs
var orderedList = list.OrderBy(number => number).ToList();
var index = orderedList.LastIndexOf(myNumber) + 1
var result = index < list.Count
    ? list[index]
    : throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Highest number already reached")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here an extended version of Sean's answer:

```
var index = list.BinarySearch(myNumber);
if (index >= 0)
{
    int nextNumber = list[index + 1];
    Console.WriteLine("NextNumber: " + nextNumber);

    int previousNumber = list[index - 1];
    Console.WriteLine("PreviousNumber: " + previousNumber);
}
else
{
    // Not found
    var newIndex = ~index;
    if (newIndex > list.Count - 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("myNumber wasn't found in list, myNumber is higher than any entry in list");
        Console.WriteLine("NextNumber: " + int.MaxValue);
        Console.WriteLine("PreviousNumber: " + list[newIndex - 1]);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("myNumber wasn't found in list, newIndex is the next higher number");
        Console.WriteLine("NextNumber: " + list[newIndex]);

        if (newIndex == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("myNumber is lower than any entry in list");
            Console.WriteLine("PreviousNumber: " + int.MinValue);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("PreviousNumber: " + list[newIndex - 1]);
        }
    }
}
```

You can see it in action here:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/g1cbMb